# Create a zip file from an array of bytea images

Tags: php

I have an array which stores images retrieved from a Postgresql database with the bytea datatype.

I tested my code and it successfully downloads one image to my computer

```
<?php
   require_once('database.php');
   $db = new Database();

   $imageArray = $db->getRandomScrapedImagePack();

   header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=image.jpg');
   echo pg_unescape_bytea($imageArray[0]);
?>
```

But `$imageArray` contains more than one image. I would like to create a zip file from all the images in `$imageArray` then download the zip file containing all the images.

Would this be possible without writing the images to disk first? if so I would appreciate any references on how this is done.

**UPDATE**

So this is what I came up with, but it's not creating the zip file on the server. The file that gets downloaded is under 1kb and when I try to unzip it I get an error that it's not a zip file

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

   require_once('database.php');
   $db = new Database();

   $imageArray = $db->getRandomScrapedImagePack();

   $zipname = 'images.zip';
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
   $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
   foreach ($imageArray as $file) {
     $zip->addFile($file);
   }
   $zip->close();

   header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=images.zip');
   echo $zip;
?>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have made updates that the images get saved to disk first and then into a zip file. The strange thing now is that when I run the file through my browser, no file gets created. But when I run it through the command line it works fine

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

   require_once('../database.php');
   $db = new Database();

   $imageArray = $db->getRandomScrapedImagePack();
   $imagePathArray = array();

   $counter = 0;
   foreach($imageArray as $image) {
     $imagePath = "photo" . $counter++ .".jpg";
     array_push($imagePathArray, $imagePath);
     $fp = fopen($imagePath, 'w');
     fwrite($fp, pg_unescape_bytea($image));
     fclose($fp);
   }

   $fileName = "images.zip";
   //create the archive
   $zip = new ZipArchive();

   if($zip->open($fileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time</p>";
    return false;
   }

   //add the files
   foreach($imagePathArray as $path) {
     $zip->addFile($path);
   }

   //close the zip -- done!
   $zip->close();

   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fileName."\"");
   readfile($fileName);

?>
```

**UPDATE 3**

So the following code creates the zip file without writing the images to disk first. But it only works when I run it through the command line.

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

   require_once('../database.php');
   $db = new Database();

   $imageArray = $db->getRandomScrapedImagePack();

   $zipname = 'images.zip';
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
   $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
   $counter = 0;
   foreach ($imageArray as $file) {
     $zip->addFromString($counter++ . ".jpg", pg_unescape_bytea($file));
   }
   $zip->close();

   header('Content-Disposition: Attachment;filename=images.zip');
   readfile($zipname);
?>
```

Comment: I noticed you deleted your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40599620/1415724 I take it that what I posted in there helped you solve it, correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am testing it now. But initially I wanted to do it all through ram, I think with what you posted, it writes it to disk first right?

Comment: Not when using a header, I don't think it does write to disk.

Comment: ok I will test it soon

Comment: oh wait, I think you may be right. Zipping files does require certain read/writes so it would be very hard to find something that won't.

Comment: I'll be fine with it writing to disk. But it's not working. I will update mt question so I can post about it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think the reason for it not working is that,  $zip->addFile($file); expects a file path, not binary data stored in the variable. Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, Have a read in the manual for it. http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php - Try out a few examples from there. If it works, you'll know that you need to get the syntax just right for the file/path array.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you please read update2

Comment: @Arya your "update 1" should work, just use `->addFromString` instead of `->addFile` http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php

Comment: @chiliNUT I tried your suggestion and it works. But only through the command line. When I access it through the browser, the zip file does not get created on the server. Similar results when saving the images to disk too. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: It's fixed. I checked the logs and it was a permission isssue

Comment: @Arya lol its always a permission issue